# collectionView cell width not changing for different nib

Tags: ios, swift, nib, collectionview

I have a collection view which is nested inside of a table view cell. The first cell in the collection view is a button which allows users to create a new list. Its width is smaller than that of the main lists cells. I recently changed the code around so that the collectionView delegate and dataSource methods are in the tableViewController instead of the table view cell, however now the first cells width is not changing as it did before moving the code. This picture shows:

[image]

If I press into the blank space it is registering that I clicked the plus cell.

The code for all the collectionView delegate and dataSource methods:

```
extension ProfileTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("the media: \(usersLists.count)")
    return usersLists.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addNewListCell", for: indexPath) as! addNewListCell

        cell.currentUser = currentUser

        return cell

    }else{

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as! userListsCell

        cell.layer.applySketchShadow()
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = false

        cell.currentUser = currentUser
        cell.media = usersLists[indexPath.item-1]

        return cell
    }

}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    if indexPath.item == 0 {

        let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 158)
        return size

    }else{

        let size = CGSize(width: 158, height: 158)
        return size

    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        //button
        self.addListDelegate?.addNewItem()
    }
}
```

I tested if changing any values in the size in `sizeForItemAt` would change the cell size and nothing changes in any cells

the table view methods which are in the ProfileTableViewController class and not the extension:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell", for: indexPath) as! profileCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? profileCell else { return }

    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row) //this line sets the collectionView delegate and datasouce so that I can have all of the collectionView methods in this class

}
```

and this is the code inside of the tableViewCell

```
protocol addListCollectionDelegate: class {
    func addNewItem()
}

class profileCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {    

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "usersLists", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "listCell")
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "newListCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "addNewListCell")

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
        <D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>
        (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to change the width of the first cell since `sizeForItemAt` is not changing the size? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add this protocol: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

It is required when you want to return custom size for an item.

Also improve your code like below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addNewListCell", for: indexPath) as! addNewListCell
        cell.currentUser = currentUser
        return cell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as! userListsCell
    cell.layer.applySketchShadow() // Write this line in cell class
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20 // Write this line in cell class
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false // Write this line in cell class
    cell.currentUser = currentUser
    cell.media = usersLists[indexPath.item - 1]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    return indexPath.item == 0 ? CGSize(width: 80, height: 158) : CGSize(width: 158, height: 158)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method. In Xcode 11 or later, you need to set Estimate Size to none from Xib.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   let padding: CGFloat =  170
   let collectionViewSize = advertCollectionView.frame.size.width - padding
   return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
}
```

Comment: How to set exactly the estimate size to none?

Comment: Select collection view from storyboard then go to size inspector (scale image option) on left side bar of storyboard you will see estimate size option in second row, there you can set estimate size to None, Automatic or Custom.